# Close modal popup while clicking outside of popup in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have the popup modal in one of my app. I would like to close this popup while clicking outside of modal. I can achieve this behaviour using JavaScript but I can't quite find a way to make this work using Svelte framework. For now I'm achieving that behaviour like this

```js
if (e.target.classList.contains('my-modal')){
    e.target.style.display="none";
}
```

but I would like to have this worked using Svelte.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A common way to solve this is to have a background element behind the modal that covers the screen and intercepts click events: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.57.1&example=modal-with-slot

This is also a good way to (for example) fade out the background to make the modal more visible.

Another approach is to use the special `<:Window>` component to listen for clicks, and stop the propagation of any clicks that begin inside the modal: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.57.1&gist=ba5f8a78263f2cdfbc16b1ae8732da5d

```html
<:Window on:click='set({ message: "clicked outside the box" })'/>

<div class='clickzone' on:click='event.stopPropagation()'>
  <div class='inner' on:click='set({ message: "clicked inside the box" })'>
    {{message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `on:click|stopPropagation` for a shorter syntax

Comment: My working code looks like:
<div class="modal" on:click={(e)=> hide()}>
    <div class="modal-content" on:click|stopPropagation>

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this in 2023 or later, the syntax has been updated to `<svelte:window />` instead of `<:window />`.

```html
<svelte:window on:click='set({ message: "clicked outside the box" })' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this repo for `on:outclick` event:
https://github.com/babakfp/svelte-outclick

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the "onclick" handler on the root div:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" on:click={ () => send('CLOSE') }>
```

I use XState to send the 'CLOSE' event to the state machine, on another examples where people just use a flag variable you can do like this:

```
<script>
  export let open = false;
  export let onClosed;

  const modalClose = () => {
    open = false;
    if (onClosed) {
      onClosed();
    }
  }
</script>

{#if open}
  <div class="modal" on:click={modalClose} >
  ...
```

I didn't have to add the `stopPropagation` flag on the internal buttons as I think Svelte manage automatically, but just in case you need it, inside your modal `on:click` logic you can add the flag: `on:click|stopPropagation`

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" on:click={modalClose}>
    Close
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" on:click|stopPropagation={yourSaveLogic()}>
    Save changes
  </button>
</div>
```